# Dialog 'apprequests' friend invites send OK but never get through. (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook, invite, apprequests

I'm having problems getting friend invites working. They seem to be being sent OK (I don't get any errors from the iOS delegates) but the invites never appear on the receivers FB account. I'm using iOS SDK and logging in with test users. The code I'm using to create the invite dialog is:

`NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`
`[dict setValue:@"Accept my invite" forKey:@"message"];`
`[_facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:dict andDelegate:self];`

This brings up the dialog where I can select friends to invite. When I hit Send the dialog vanishes and no errors are returned. Problem is that the invites are never received by the people I send them to.

I have set my canvas url, so according to other posts on SO everything should be working fine... but they are not.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "When I hit Send the dialog vanishes and no errors are returned. "  What do you get for the response?

Comment: On the receiving end, do you check for incoming requests using a regular browser or the mobile version? In order to get requests on mobile browsers, you need to specify a URL for a Mobile Web app too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is explained in [Requests documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/):

> User to User Requests are only available for Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

Same stated about App to User requests as well.

This is probably not only because Canvas URL, but also application type (I guess it shouldn't be native to display request)

In fact requests are sent but users not able to see 'em. You can access requests (via Graph API) for users of your application and display 'em in your app.

Comment: Other apps like 'Path' successfully post invites which can be seen on the Facebook website. I don't think it's because the invite is coming from an iOS App.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: (Sending Invitations, getting ID in response, but no Notification alert or request on facebook.......).

Please first remove all requests from your facebook. Then send invitation.(If getting ID in response), then it will be shown 100%.

This is a problem with facebook, it doesn't shows latest requests on top if max notifications/requests reached.(It hides new notifications/request).